# Ajax.BeginForm not replace itself when using Html.Editors

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have a main view (Index.cshtml)

```
@model AjaxTests.Models.MainModel
<div id="mainDiv">
    @Html.Partial( "AjaxFormPartial", Model )
</div>
```

and AjaxFormPartial.cshtml:

```
@model AjaxTests.Models.MainModel

@using( Ajax.BeginForm( "AjaxFormAction", "AjaxForm", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "mainDiv" } ) )
{
    @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.Id, new { value = Model.Id} );
    @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Name, new { value = Model.Name} );
    @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Description, new { value = Model.Description} );
    <input type="submit" value ="Send" />
}
```

The controller method fired by ajax is:

```
public ActionResult AjaxFormAction( MainModel model )
{
    model.Name += "XYZ";
    model.Description += "ABC;
    return PartialView( "AjaxFormPArtial", model } );
}
```

and model:

```
public class MainModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

So ajax should replace itself = render again AjaxFormPartial with new values passed in model from controller.
The problem is, that values in editors stay the same. I put breakpoint in AjaxFormPartial  and I can see that model changed, but in browser values stays the same.
Interesting, that when instead of @Html.TextBoxFor I use ordinary p, h1 and similar html tags values are changing.
More over - when in debug mode debugger stop on breakpoint, and I move down "yellow arrow" to next line, bypassing first TextBoxFor the view change = not display this missed textbox, but second one display UNCHANGED value.

Can someone explain me, why values in textbox not change  to new values from model after ajax call ?

thanks in advance